# Pass multiple variables to render json in rails cotroller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to pass the data from controller to javascript. This is how you do it,

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: {data: @data} }
end
```

And then in your view file, you should do this:

```
<%= javascript_tag do%>
  window.data = <%= raw @data.to_json %>
<%end%>

<script>
  for( i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
    alert(data[i]);
  }
</script>
```

Make sense. Right?

However, above code is when you are passing only one variable in json code i.e. data variable. What I need to do is to pass multiple variables to my javascript code.

It should be done as:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: {data: @data, data1: @data1, data2: @data2} }
end
```

Now,
- How should I access the data1 & data2 variables in my view file?
- Do I need to modify window.data? I tried the below code though and it did not work out. Gave me argument error.

```
<%= javascript_tag do%>
  window.data = <%= raw @data.to_json, @data1.to_json %>
<%end%>
```

Any leads would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `render json` call will render a single object, so try to store all the data in a single JSON object (or array):

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: {all_data: {data: @data, data1: @data1, data2: @data2}}}
end
```

On the front end:

```
<%= javascript_tag do%>
  window.data = <%= raw @all_data.to_json %>
<%end%>
```

Now `window.data` should have everything you need in `window.data.data` , `window.data.data1` , `window.data.data2`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

However, I am afraid to tell you that I am not able to see the expected result with that.

I did exactly what you asked me do but doing `alert window.data` gives me null in my javascript.

Comment: You'll need to create `all_data` in your ruby model as well, if you show your model, I can try to update...

Comment: Interesting. Although, I did not need to create anything if I pass single variable. 

How should I add it in model btw?

Comment: Read up on [creating ActiveRecord Models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#creating-active-record-models)  ... what we have above is a hack, ideally, you'd want to have `render json: @product` and put your model definition in models/product.rb ... also read on [layouts and rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: Although I knew most of these models and layout/rendrings, but still I took a quick look at the pages you gave. But unfortunately, I am not able to get past to it.. 

What do I need to create in ruby model? Which model?

Comment: That really depends on your requirements, models should represent real world data: `Product`, `Employee` ... not something abstract and non-descriptive like `Data`... you can get up and running quickly using an [ActiveRecord model generator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#model-generators)

Comment: Hmmm. I understand that. But in this case, my 'data' does not really belongs to any model. Let just say that It just contains data about the Product and Employee both..